# $\int \dfrac{1}{4x^2+1} \ dx $ - why is it $\dfrac{1}{2} \arctan(2x)+c$ not $\arctan(2x)+c$?

Tags: integration

$\int \dfrac{1}{4x^2+1} \ dx $ - why is it $\dfrac{1}{2} \arctan(2x)+c$ not $\arctan(2x)+c$?

I've been looking at my formula booklet which gives the integral as:

$$\int \dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\dfrac{1}{a} \arctan(\dfrac{x}{a})+c$$

So I just plugged the numbers in... and got it wrong :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now others have pointed out (even if without using the term explicitly) that the chain rule is needed.

However, let's look at your formula from the book and how it applies here.
$$
\int\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2} = \frac 1 a \arctan\frac x a + C.
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{4x^2+1} = \int\frac{dx}{4\left(x^2+\frac 1 4\right)} = \frac 1 4 \int\frac{dx}{x^2+\left(\frac 1 2 \right)^2}
\end{align}
So $a=1/2$ and we have $1/4$ in front of the whole thing.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, thank you :) So in general, you should always factor out the coefficient of the $x^2$ term?

Comment: @Jim : In many contexts that makes sense, especially if there is a first-degree term in the quadratic polynomial, since then you would often need to complete the square. But it's not necessarily the only way to proceed.  In this case it seemed like the simplest way to reduce it to something to which the formula in the book is directly applicable.

Comment: BTW, it may be worth understanding this: $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2} = \frac 1 a \int\frac{dx/a}{(x/a)^2 + 1} = \frac 1 a\int\frac{du}{u^2+1} = \frac 1 a \arctan u + C=\frac 1 a \arctan\frac x a + C$. ${}\qquad{}$